# How to disable Chrome's Sign In tab prompt when starting the browser with logged out Google account?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Chrome. I have a habit of always signing out of my Google account before turning off my computer. Every time I start up Chrome after turning on the computer the next day, Chrome would automatically open a new tab called "Sign in" to prompt me to sign in to my Google account.

[image]

I don't like this auto-opened tab. Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: Changing "On startup" settings affects this behaviour?

Comment: I don't think think the "On startup" settings are related to this